# How to add align forms input fields and add spaces between them?

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to make a login page but can't seem to make the form fields align and have reasonable space between them and the name.

Here's how it currently looks like: [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjLuZ.jpg)

Here's how I want it to look like: [Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivpon.jpg)

My current code looks like this

```
<b>Username:</b><input type="text" name="username"> <br/>
<b>Password:</b><input type="password" name="pass"> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log in"/> <br/>
```

Comment: Why not use a table to align it in columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without doing a decent amount more to create a better grid system (personally, I use Bootstrap to help with this), this would work for this specific form. I would suggest looking into HTML markup as you weren't using `<label>` tags at all.

You can create some custom classes so it doesn't affect other inputs and labels on your page.

```css
.input-container{
  display: block;
}

.input-label{
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-input{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.button-input{
  margin-left: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <label for="username" class="input-label">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" class="text-input">
</div>
<div class="input-container">
  <label for="pass" class="input-label">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" class="text-input">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="button-input" />
```

Comment: This works and it's simple, thanks! Also, why use labels for the form though? Any benefits for it?

Comment: i think `br` is not a good idea for styling, wrapping element inside divs or any block element is better.

Comment: Good call @TemaniAfif, I usually do but had copied what was here. My answer was updated accordingly.

Comment: good, and you can remove the display:block and keep the class .. as by default it's block :)

Comment: I was actually going to comment on that, but held off. Depending on the reset stylesheet or other styles that were used, I don't like to rely on the implied styles of elements, especially with beginners who like to define styles on the element level without understanding the downstream effects.

Answer (score 1):

Simply consider some margin :

```css
input {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<b>Username:</b><input type="text" name="username"><br/>
<b>Password:</b><input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log in"><br/>
```

And for a better html structure you may do something like this  :

```css
.container {
  max-width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}

label input {
  float: right;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></label>
  <label>Password: <input type="password" name="pass"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</div>
```

Comment: What's the benefits of using a container and labels for the forms?

Comment: @Anonimotipy try clicking on the text and you will get the focus on the needed input ;) this is the use of label .. the container will allow you to have everything inside an element that you can easily style and no need to style each element alone like adding spaces, alignement, etc

Comment: @Anonimotipy  for example i used `font-weight: bold;` to style all the text inside, so no need to add `b` to each one

Comment: @Anonimotipy you should also avoid using `br` to style as it not very good when you will have many elements